# How do you prevent PSQL from printing out a bunch of information to stdout when you first connect?

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I connect to psql, it dumps a bunch of config info to stdout when I connect. For example:

```
Expanded display is used automatically.
Null display is "¤".
Line style is unicode.
Unicode border line style is "single".
Unicode column line style is "single"
```

This causes a problem when I try to copy things over stdout, as those lines get included in the output thus resulting in invalid csv files.

Example:

```
psql -c "copy (select * from foo limit 10) to stdout csv header" > ~/path/to/myfile.csv
```

Output:

```
Expanded display is used automatically.
Null display is "¤".
Line style is unicode.
Unicode border line style is "single".
Unicode column line style is "single"
id,name
foo,bar
baz,bazzeer
```

How do I silence all of those initial informational prints to stdout?

Comment: [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) `--quiet` or `-q`: 'Specifies that psql should do its work quietly. By default, it prints welcome messages and various informational output. If this option is used, none of this happens. This is useful with the -c option. This is equivalent to setting the variable QUIET to on.'

Comment: @AdrianKlaver aha! That did the trick!